# PHP - Wildcard to find file?

Tags: php, wildcard

I'm trying to make a PHP script to list everything in a directory but I want to exclude certain files ending in desc.txt as they'll take up too much space in the list. (They're there to provide descriptions to the actual script of each folder/file)

```
if ($file !== "." && $file !== ".." && $file !== "desc.txt"){
```

That hides the whole "../" button to go up a directory and stuff, but I really can't figure out how to make it hide files ending in desc.txt. I tried * and % and glob and all that other stuff but nothing has worked so I just have it there as desc.txt, any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `glob()`?

Comment: It wouldn't work, couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Not even `$files = glob($directory . '*.{txt}', GLOB_BRACE);`?

Comment: ForguesR fixed it but thank you!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
if ($file !== "." && $file !== ".." && substr($file, -8) !== "desc.txt"){ );
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! I've been sitting here for the past hour trying to figure something out!